# Creating a table which can auto update if some column in other table got changed

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have created two tables in postgresql say a and b.
So what i want if i change data in table 'a' data in table 'b' automatically got updated at the same time. 
Or if data in table be such that b.salary= 2000+x where x is variable and it will be passed to table.
If any one of the problem get solved i can carry out my work further.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Brief_Real-world_Trigger_Example

Comment: What you need is a trigger:http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/introduction-to-mysql-triggers/

Comment: If you want to get help without showing your code at least be **much more** specific: post exact table schemas, sample data, desired outcome.

Comment: Hey thanks to all of u, Sorry for responding late trigger idea worked but what i realizes that using trigger i have to run query that do the same thing but consumes extra time, suppose there exist a column in my table x whose all entries are 0, and when data entered in table y the column in Xupdated to 10, but what i want all the entries in column of table x is in form K+(value of cell in table Y) so if value of cell in table Y set to 5 then cells of table X updates to K+5 without using any query in trigger function. If you guys want more clarification i can give some more examples.

Comment: If you want new data in a table, the answer is still _trigger_. If you want something like a spreadsheet, the answer is _a view_.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test.x (
   value integer
);

CREATE FUNCTION test.value_calc(_arg integer) RETURNS integer AS
$$
DECLARE
   C_MODIFIER CONSTANT integer = 1000;  -- ;)
BEGIN
   RETURN _arg + C_MODIFIER;  -- there you can put any logic
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE VIEW test.y AS SELECT x.value, test.value_calc(x.value) AS modified FROM test.x AS x;

INSERT INTO test.x VALUES (543);

SELECT * FROM test.y;
```

value| modified
-----+----------
  543|     1543